# Galois group and traslations by rational numbers.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Is a well known result that, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there exist an irreducible polynomial $p \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that the Galois Group of its splitting field is $S_n$.

Now my question:

> Given a polynomial $g(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ of degree $n$ is true
>   that there exist a rational number $q$ such that the Galois Group of
>   $g(x)+q$ is $S_n$?

**Edit**: A more complicated question:

> Let's fix $g(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ of degree $n$ and define $GAL(n)$
>   as the set of groups that can be realized as Galois Group of a
>   polynomial of degree $n$.
>
> Consider the map from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $GAL(n)$ that sends $q \in\mathbb{Q}$ to $Gal (g(x)+q)$.
>
> Is this map surjective?

Comment: The answer to the first question (and hence also the second) is no, unless you assume something more about the polynomial (take $g(x) = x^n$ to see this).

Comment: Do you think that could be more interesting if such polynomial is squarefree?

Comment: I am not sure what sort of condition on the polynomial will work (if any will). I think for degree $5$ the polynomial $x^5 + x$ works (but I might recall incorrectly.

Comment: Maybe you should revert to the original here and ask the new version as a new question. It seems a shame that the answer now doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Take $g(x)=x^4$, and consider the polynomial $x^4+q$, where $q$ is a rational number.

If $q$ is negative, then the roots of $x^4+q$ in $\mathbb{C}$ are $\sqrt[4]{-q}, i\sqrt[4]{-q}, -\sqrt[4]{-q}$ and $-i\sqrt[4]{-q}$, where $\sqrt[4]{-q}$ is the positive real fourth root of $-q$.  Then the decomposition field of $x^4+q$ is
$$ \mathbb{Q}( \sqrt[4]{-q}, i\sqrt[4]{-q}) =  \mathbb{Q}( \sqrt[4]{-q}, i)$$
which has degree at most $8$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.  Thus the Galois group has order at most $8$, and cannot be $S_4$.

Now, if $q$ is positive, then take $\zeta = e^{i\pi/4}$, a primitive eight root of unity.  Then the roots of $x^4+q$ are $\zeta \sqrt[4]{q}, \zeta^3 \sqrt[4]{q}, \zeta^5 \sqrt[4]{q}$ and $\zeta^7 \sqrt[4]{q}$.  The field of decomposition is then
$$ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta \sqrt[4]{q}, i),$$
which again is of degree at most $8$.

Comment: I've just seen @TobiasKildetoft's comment above.  This answer is just a computation of a special case of his remark.

Comment: Taking $g(x) = x^4+2$ instead, you get the same result, but this time $g(x)$ is both squarefree and irreducible.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I think the real interesting condition is $g'(x) \notin (x)$

Comment: @JosephCurwen, your suggestion is good, but it’s specific to the point $x=0$ on the line, while the question is invariant under translations of the line. I think that when you smear your suggestion over the whole line, it becomes the hypothesis that $g$ has all roots simple. [ Whoops — not quite right, but I’ll leave what I said anyway. ]